# How to calculate sum of last n elements of an array using Arr.reduceRight

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am able to calculate the sum of last n elements of an array using for loop as below. How can I achieve the same using Arr.reduceRight?

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5];
y = 0
for(let i=x.length; i>x.length-3; i--) {
  console.log(x[i-1]);
  y +=x[i-1];

}
console.log(y);
```

Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrNxZB?editors=0011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `reduceRight` (or reduce), there is 2 arguments

1. A callback
2. The initial value (optional, in that case `last/first` will be init value, and it will start from `second-last/second` for `reduceRight/reduce` accordingly)

Now the callback having 4 arguments,

1. The accumulator (what we returned (each) last time, init or last/first value for the first time)
2. Each entry (from second last/second depending on init value passed or not)
3. Current index
4. The Entire Collection (This is mostly useful when you are in a continuous chain)

All you have to do is, (assuming you have to add last `N` number)

`IF (Collection length - Current index) <= N` **Then** *Add Current Value with sum and return*

`ELSE` *Return Current Sum ignoring current value*

So you can do,

`array.reduceRight((sum, each, idx, a) => (a.length - idx) > N  ? sum : sum + each , 0)`

Now, you can remove the ternary and do **(**`sum +` either `0` or `Each Number`**)** conditionally

so `sum + ((array.length - idx) <= N && each)`

If the condition `(array.length - idx) <= N` is false it will return false and it will not go to the and operator otherwise it will return value of `each`, so it will add `false` (0) or `each value` conditionally

`array.reduceRight((sum, each, idx, a) => sum + ((a.length - idx) <= N && each), 0)`

```js
let arr = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000],
  N = 4,
  sum = arr.reduceRight((s, e, i, a) => s + ((a.length - i) <= N && e), 0);
  
console.log(`Sum of last ${N} values: :`, sum);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can first `slice` the array, then `reduce` the resulting array. No need for `reduceRight` as the sum operation is commutative.

```js
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

n = 4;

y = x.slice(-n).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);

console.log(y);
```

Comment: I had this idea but as OP is specifically asking for using `reduceRight`, I did not go with this approach

Comment: @Rajesh take my answer as "alternative to" :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure over a count `c` and check this values and decrement and take the value with a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()).

This proposal uses [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight), as wanted.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    sum = array.reduceRight((c => (s, v) => s + (c && c-- && v))(3), 0)

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: This is a horrible solution regarding readability and understandability.

Answer (score 0):

```js
x = [1,2,3,4,5];
n = 3; // How many numbers to take
console.log(x.slice(-n).reduceRight((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0))
```

`reduceRight` takes two arguments: a callback and the initial value. We initialise it to 0 as we are counting.

`curr` in my example will be 3, then 4 then 5. `prev` will be 0, then 3, then 7.

See: [Array.ReduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight)

Answer (score 0):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight

has a good example on almost exactly that.

```js
const elementCountToLeaveOut = 3;

console.log([1,2,3,4,5].reduceRight((acc, val, idx) => idx >= elementCountToLeaveOut ? acc + val : acc))
```

Comment: Even my approach is similar. You can refer to my answer to check the missing part

Comment: they are all mathematicians, he just wronged the number of the elementCountToLeaveOut.
change the '3' to the '2' and it works

Comment: @Leo Nope. The logic is wrong. If you have an array of `[1, ..., 100]` and I say, sum last 10 number, in this logic, it will sum last 90 numbers and not 10. Hence my previous comment to refer my answer.

Comment: @JamesHulse Which is the expected result if you leave out the leftmost 3 elements.

Comment: @JamesHulse @Rajesh @Leo check the variable name `elementCountToLeaveOut`. It does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var n = 4;
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var y = x.reduceRight(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
  if (n > 0) { // If n = 0, stop calculating the sum.
    accumulator += currentValue;
  }
  n--; // Reducing n value for every loop.
  return accumulator;
}, 0);

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple :

```js
var x = [1,2,3,4,5];
var n = 2;
var y = x.reduceRight((accumulator, currentValue, index) =>{
          if(index < x.length-n) return accumulator;
          return accumulator + currentValue;
       }, 0);

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this logic:

- Create a variable of final index(`fIndex`) where the loop should end.
- Then you can loop using `reduceRight` and check if passed index is smaller then `fIndex`

  - If yes, return last calculated value
  - If no, return sum value.

```js
function sumRight(arr, n) {
  var fIndex = arr.length - n;
  return arr.reduceRight(function(sum, num, index) {
    return index < fIndex ? sum : sum + num
  }, 0)
}

var x = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(sumRight(x, 3))
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this one

```
lastN=(x,n)=>(m=x.length-n,x.reduceRight((a,v,i)=>{return a+=i>=m?v:0;},0))
```

Comment: Did you see other answers before posting? This is exactly the same to my answer, minus explanation and readability.

Comment: This answer is not exactly the same as you. At least my answer has a side effect instead of yours. Second one. I think that this type of code is not a "rocket science" and no need a lot of explanation. 
And third. Do you always check posted answers?